# "If it should" vs "If it does" vs "Should it"

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

What is the difference between:

> 1) **If my car should break down**, please, call the mechanic.
>
> 2) **If my car breaks down**, please, call the mechanic.
>
> 3) **Should my car break down**, please, call the police

I read that the first variant is informal whilst the third one is formal. But what is the second then?

Answer (score 1):

#2 is the informal, conversational version.

#1 and #3 have no difference in meaning and are both more formal than #2 due to the use of "should".

See also: [Should versus If](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/84695/74178).

Comment: The third one is semi-archaic, and should be used with caution, as it may be harder to understand.

Comment: While first one is fully archaic?

Comment: I wouldn't say that either #1 or #3 are archaic or hard to understand--only that they are formal. Their usage may be "archaic" in the sense that 'twas once more popular than 'tis currently, but they are still valid and not totally uncommon.

Comment: Okay if the 2 is informal, how to say it formal? It will be "If my car will break down, please, call the mechanic" or what?